# Is Akka PoisonPill propagated to children

Tags: scala, akka, actor, kill

If I have an Actor `A` with Child `C` and send a `PoisonPill` to `C` - will `A` forward the `PoisonPill` to `C` or will it `context.stop(C)`?

I have a setup where it is very well possible that `A` creates work to be handled by `C`. So I want `A` to terminate once it processes all the messages that arrived prior to the `PoisonPill` (meanwhile messages to `C` are sent) and have `C` process all these messages until it terminates too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think Akka forwards the `PoisonPill`. When an actor receives a `PoisonPill` it calls `self.stop()`. You can see that here in the `Akka` source code:

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/f008a932c381013f6060ee00a731862bafed2be7/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorCell.scala#L514

When calling `stop` in an Actor, that calls `stop` in all its children recursively. `stop` will allow the current message to be processed but it will discard the remaining messages in the mailbox.